# merge of vertices not working

Tags: mesh, vertices

When I select a couple vertices, open the context menu, and try to "Merge Vertices", it doesn't do anything.  The vertices stay exactly where they are like no action was performed.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: are the 2 vertices inside the same object or have you selected 2 objects?

Comment: two different objects I'm trying to join together

Comment: yeah, answered my own question there I guess.  I merged them together and now the merge vertices works.  Thanks for the hint.